# JavaScript convert date with local Timezone and legal time offset

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am working on a conversion of an UTC date.
The date format received from the server inside the JSON file has the following format:

```
"OpenDate":"2015-10-26T08:00:00Z"
```

I translate the date using the following function:

```
var myDate = myJson.OpenDate.toLocaleString();
```

The problem occurs after 25th of October, when the legal time is changed. After 25th of October my dates are 1 hour earlier, which they shouldn't. So how can I keep into consideration the change in time? If the appointment says 8 a.m. UTC it should be always 9 a.m. for our timezone, even when the legal time is changed.

Comment: That format of date and time string will be correctly parsed by ES5 compliant browsers, but not all browsers in use are ES5 compliant and so will return NaN (e.g. IE 8). For ES5 browsers, you should parse it as: `new Date(string)`. For the rest, you should parse it yourself. The 1 hour difference in **local** time might be due to transition to daylight saving time, but it will not affect the internal time value, which is UTC and unaffected by daylight saving.

Comment: The problem is the conversion. At the moment the conversion is correct but toLocaleString() return the daylight saving time. This is what is wrong

Comment: The specification for [*toLocaleString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.5) is implementation dependent, so whatever the developers think is a good idea and not consistent across browsers. If you want a specific format, you'll have to use the various [*get**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.9) methods to get the values and write them out.

Comment: I understand, at this point is easier to write a custom formatter and adapt it to angular